# How to solve Suspicious Link error in email which is sent from website

Tags: email, go, https, smtp, google-workspace

I'm sending a reset password email from my Go RESTFUL web service to our users and I'm using Go SMTP and google Gsuite domain which info@mycompanyname.ca! I've tested it before and it works but when I send it to one of our users he gets Suspicious Link error. He's using the Gmail website. I checked the https and both my website and links are https and When he forwards the email to me I don't see this error anymore! Can anybody help me with this?

This is my code :

```
        mime string = "MIME-version: 1.0;\nContent-Type: text/html; 
        charset=\"UTF-8\";\n\n"
        hostname string = "smtp.gmail.com"

        auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", username, password, hostname)

        data := map[string]string{"Token": token}
        buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)

        t, err := template.ParseFiles(htmlFilename)
        if err != nil {
                return err 
        }   

        err = t.Execute(buffer, data)
        if err != nil {
                return err 
        }   

        msg := []byte(subject + mime + buffer.String())
        reciever = append(reciever, clientMail)

        return smtp.SendMail(hostname+":587", auth, "", reciever, msg)
}
```

And this is HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
    <meta name="author" content="some name">
    <meta name="description" content="Entry HTML page for the dashboard">
    </head>
    <body style="max-width: 50rem; margin: auto; margin-top: 1rem;">
    <img src="https://address in google drive" style="margin:auto;
    display: block; width: 17rem; height: 4.6rem; position: relative; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);"
    alt="logo" title="company logo" />
    <div style="margin-top: 0.5rem; padding-left: 0.5rem; padding-right: 0.5rem; border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray; background-color: #f9f9f9">
    <h3>Hello!</h3>
    <p>You receive this email because this is your first time logging in. To enter your account,
    you will need to set a password. Click the button below to set it.</p>
    <div style="text-align: center">
    <a href="https://websiteAddress/#/changepasswordapi?token={{ .Token }}" target="_blank">
    <button style="cursor: pointer; border: none; width: 50%; background-color: #ED5E28;
    color: white; font-size: 1rem; height: 2.5rem;
    border-radius: 0.35rem"><strong>Set Password</strong></button>
    </a>
    </div>
    <p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email. The password setup is only valid for the next 24 hours.</p>
    <p>Thanks,</p>
    <p>compaynName Team</p>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 0.8rem; color: gray">
    <p>&copy; 2019 companyName. All rights reserved.</p>
    <p>company addr</p>
    <P>company city</P>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you please add code that deals with sending the reset password e-mail?

Comment: I don't think suspicious link has anything to do with the email, it's that the domain is considered potentially harmful/malicious.

Comment: Yes, added to my question @daplho

Comment: The domain is https and the link i'm using in html is https too @Adrian

Comment: HTTPS alone doesn't mean it's safe. You could be on a malicious sites list or it could have detected suspicious content or something.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what is suspicious about it. Can I send the Html? @Adrian

Comment: I have seen this myself with my own emails. However, after a while the problem stopped without action on my part. Google could be using some type of analysis to guess potential problem sites (new domain name, not seen this email before) - I am just guessing. The fact that your email has the word "password" will hit the trigger with most security systems.

Comment: This looks like a security feature of gmail. See [enable less secure apps](https://www.jotform.com/help/392-How-to-Use-Your-Gmail-Account-as-Your-Email-Sender-via-SMTP)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I solved this problem. At first, I thought that might be G Suite problem, So I called them and I realized it's not because I could see our email in the inbox and not in the spam folder. So I tried [this link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020) and I request a review for our domain. After about 30 hours the problem was gone!